# Hibernate 3 - many query in current session

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

in a point of session i want to launch a block of code that executes 
12000 select and 4810 insert (it's a for cycle that i have a list of Object where i can set 5 property and for each i launch saveOrUpdate).

My problem consist that in Eclipse console i found an error. But if i relaunch this block of code, the line of error changes.

I think that the problem is the lot of querys or a cache problem or i dont know.
Immediatly the error:

```
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1928)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1701)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
at ........(***myfile:this line changes on every launch***)
```

In System.out.println, i control that the where condition of hibernate query exists, and effectly there is no problem for thats.

The error appears in mid- execution and not at the beginning so do not think is a problem where condition.

The type of query is simple:

```
List<ObjectForMe>  list = (List<ObjectForMe>) getSession(em) (method for my session)
.createCriteria(ObjectForMe.class)                                  
.add(Restrictions.eq("propertyBigDecimal",new BigDecimal(Integer)))
.add(Restrictions.eq("propertyBigDecimal1",new BigDecimal(Integer)))
.add(Restrictions.eq("propertyRelationIstanceofObjectX",istanceofObjectX))
.list();
```

This isn't a problem with my connection jdbc. I do any type of test-connection and it's wonderful.

Thank you for help me

Comment: Please share your code too...

Answer (score 0):

How do you executes the hibernate's EntityTransaction commit ? do your commit is in a for loop ?

I suggest to not put the commit in the for loop ... just commit in the end when your entities are constructed ..

here is an example :

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction et = null;

    try {

        et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            em.persist(user[i]);
        }
        et.commit();

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (et.isActive())
            et.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: I also remove the saveOrUpdate but the error is the same.

Comment: yes, dont remove the saveorupdate ... just see where are your commits

Comment: because it is like if you commit the sql requests when you are building your entities (I think) ...

Comment: I agree ... Juste try a trick while waiting to have a good response ... Add a time sleep for 1 sec each 1000 persist ... And tell me how it works!

Comment: For the thread --- have you felt the delay introduced ? or it was the same as before?

Answer (score 0):

@Shiva my code is similar to code exposed @taboubim :

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

EntityTransaction et = null;

try {

    et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();

    for(Object o1: listObject)
    {
       select query1;
       select query2;
       select query3;
       o1.set(resultQuery1);
       o1.set(resultQuery2);
       o1.set(resultQuery3);
     //et.saveOrUpdate(o1); that i removed for test
    }
    et.commit();

} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (et.isActive())
        et.rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

the console show the error in method .list() of hibernate query but every launch of application, the line changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
Try with ehcache :

add dependency to your pom.xml if you are using maven (or download the jar file if not):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

after that add properties to your persistence.xml as follow:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

hope it resolves the issue !

Comment: nothing.. same error. i used also hql and the error is in query.toList ...  i expose this hql down

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<CUP> getCup( Integer Ex, BigDecimal per, CUF cuf)
         throws Exception {
    String hql = "SELECT distinct cup FROM Calculos cup";
    hql += " WHERE cup.cupPer = :periodo AND ";
    hql += " cup.cupEx = :Ejercicio12 AND ";
    hql += " cuf.cufIdint = :cufId ";
    org.hibernate.Query hqlQuery = getSession(em).createQuery(hql);
    hqlQuery.setParameter("periodo", per);
    hqlQuery.setParameter("Ejercicio12", new BigDecimal(Ex));
    hqlQuery.setParameter("cufId", cuf.getCufIdint());
    return hqlQuery.list();
}
```

i receive same error on jdbc connection, in line hqlQuery.list();
i have activated cache option in pom and in persistence;

The Data of table CUP has cupEx and cupPer as BigDecimal and a Relation with table cuf rappresented by cuf.getCufIdint().
If i launch the query (show_sql activated) in a Sql Editor the row is present..